# Linear transformation in $pV$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Say ideal gas is in a state $p_1$, $V_1$, $T_1$ (known). I compress this gas such as $\frac{dp}{dV}$ is a constant. I want to reach $T_2$>$T_1$ and I need the values for $\frac{dp}{dV}$.  Would it be right to picture the problem like that: say I have a point $(p_1,V_1)$ in a $pV$ diagram, and I draw the isothermal corresponding to $T_2$. Then would it be right to consider any line connecting $(p_1,V_1)$ to this isothermal as correct, as long as it corresponds to a compression?

Comment: Trying to find "the values for dp/dV", you may be looking for the full range of possible slopes.  A very steep slope will work just fine, but there is a minimum possible steepness.  Be sure to fully interpret the problem before trying to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is correct. You need to get to a point with $T_2$, so the endpoint lies somewhere on the $T_2$ isotherm. The condition $\frac{dp}{dV}=\text{const.}$ means that the curve connecting the startpoint with the endpoint is really just a line segment. And there you have it, this is exactly what you have said.